# Java - is it bad practice to do a try/catch inside a try/catch?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have some code that I want to execute if an exception happens. But that code can also generate an exception. But I have never seen people do a try/catch inside another try/catch.

Is what I am doing poor practice and maybe there is a better way of doing this:

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("some url");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

 try 
 {
     startActivity(intent);
 } 
 catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) 
 {
     // Make some alert to me

     // Now try to redirect them to the web version:
     Uri weburi = Uri.parse("some url");
     try
     {
         Intent webintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, weburi);
         startActivity(webintent);
     }
     catch ( Exception e )
     {
         // Make some alert to me                        
     }
 }
```

It seems kind of awkward. Is there something that might be wrong with it?

Comment: You might consider put the code in the catch block in its own method.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It's fine, although if your exception handling logic is that complex, you might consider breaking it out into its own function.

Answer (score 11):

It is a bad practice to write code with so many levels of nesting, especially in `try-catch` - so I would say: avoid. <del>On the other hand throwing an exception from `catch` block is unforgivable sin, so you should be very careful.</del>

My advice - extract your `catch` logic into a method (so `catch` block is simple) and make sure this method will never throw anything:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("some url");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

try 
{
    startActivity(intent);
} 
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) 
{
    // Make some alert to me

    // Now try to redirect them to the web version:
    Uri weburi = Uri.parse("some url");
    Intent webintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, weburi);
    silentStartActivity(webintent)
} 

//...

private void silentStartActivity(Intent intent) {
    try
    {
       startActivity(webintent);
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        // Make some alert to me                     
    }
}
```

Also it seems (I might be wrong) that you are using exceptions to control program flow. Consider standard return value if throwing `ActivityNotFoundException` is not an *exceptional* situation but it might happen under normal circumstances.

Comment: thanks...why do you say throwing an exception in a try/catch is a sin? :)

Comment: "So many levels?" I see a grand total of three. His logic in the `catch` block is no deeper than an `if` block in his `try` block would be.

Comment: The problem I saw with breaking it up is that I don't know how to check for the condition of whether the exception will happen or not since I am trying to go to an external url.

Comment: @GeekedOut: It's the *handling* that you might extract into a function. But see also Tomasz's just-added point about using exceptions to control program flow (an anti-pattern), which is a good point.

Comment: @GeekedOut: because I thought about `finally` block, not `catch` block. There is nothing wrong with throwing from `catch`, throwing from `finally` is a terrible idea because if `finally` was called due to an exception, throwing another exception will discard the original one. Sorry, I removed this part.

Comment: The tricky thing for me is that I can't know if there wont be an exception in the first or second try/catch since its going to an external url....just not how how to extract the pieces... :(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: somehow I feel that the code in `catch` block will grow and grow - so extracting method is the safest way to keep the method readable.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: Agreed on that bit.

Comment: @GeekedOut: I added some sample code with extracted method, which piece is problematic for you?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is Android API, `ActivityNotFoundException` is part of it. So that aspect of OP's code is legit.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you - much appreciated for all your input to help me learn ;)

Answer (score 6):

Answer is No..It is 100% fine.. You might have to use lot of these in JDBC and IO, because they have lot of exceptions to be handled, one inside another...

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternate solution if you don't want to use nested try and catch, 
 You can also do it like this:

```
 boolean flag = false;
 void test();
 if(flag)
  {
   test2();
  }
```

Test Method goes here:

```
private void test(){
   try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("some url");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
   }catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        System.out.println(anfe);
        flag =true;
     }
 }
```

Now put the rest code in 2nd Method:

```
public void test2(){
  Uri weburi = Uri.parse("some url");
        try
        {
           Intent webintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, weburi);
           startActivity(webintent);
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // Make some alert to me                     
        }
```

Comment: In Java, and in many other programming languages, you can write the same conditional logic many different ways. The question is why do you think your method is better, more effective, or more optimal than simply writing the second try/catch in the catch block of the first try/catch.