# How to update database table when an exception occured in business logic

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I have an api which is doing following process :-

1. Validating request
2. Saving the request in DB
3. Calling a different api synchronously to place the deal
4. Sending 201 response.

Currently if any exception is coming on step 3, we are catching it and doing following operations:-

```
try{
Step 3}
Catch(exception e){
Log
UpdateDbstate()
}
```

Where updatedb state method is updating db state and try catch again if any db exception occured.

**Problem here is if any exception occured in updatedbstate, the whole transaction will now be in inconsistent state as db is not updated**

How to correctly implement a solution around this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674474/java-is-it-bad-practice-to-do-a-try-catch-inside-a-try-catch

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `@Transactional` at service level, which would rollback the incomplete updates in db when any sql exceptions occur.

Example:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { SQLException.class })
public ResponseEntity post() {
    . . .
}
```

You can read further from this guide:
https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth